# Check if any variables are passed in a GET

Tags: php

I've done a few searches and not come up with anything, I'm sure it's obvious.

Basically I'm trying to work out if anything has been passed via GET from a form.

I know how to check for individual elements, but I just want to do a quick check if anything at all is passed

Cheers

Comment: `$variables_from_get = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') && isset($_GET);`

Comment: @Ast Derek: $_GET is always there and an array, even if PHP_SAPI==='cli' ;-)

Comment: @Ast Derek: You can send GET variables even with a POST; it's just a matter of having a URL with a querystring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful when using `count($_GET)`. If you submit the form with empty values it will still create keys for the fields, and your `count()` will be greater than 0 and `empty($_GET)` will be false.

```
<?php 
print_r($_GET);
?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea name="mytext"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Make sure the *fields* are actually not empty:

```
function ne($v) {
    return $v != '';
}

echo count($_GET);                     // prints 2
echo count(array_filter($_GET, 'ne')); // prints 0
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the job:

```
if (!empty($_GET))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( count($_GET) > 0 ) echo("I hear you!");
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(empty($_GET)) { /* no parameters passed*/}`

Answer (score 1):

just check the length of the $_GET array via count($_GET).
if none ha passed it should be 0

Answer (score 0):

Simply 'just': `if($_GET){ /* parameters passed*/}` (for the current request) works to check if *any* query-string was passed in the `GET` or `POST` request.

This is because an empty array is `false` in a boolean `if($x)` context.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

So indeed no need for `count()` or `empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it is better to check using `isset` which checks if it is defined and if it is different than null

```
if(isset($_GET['value_you_looking_for']) {//code logic here}
```

[Check for documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset)