# Checking if form element exist

Tags: php

I save the form elements to a file and the following is working as expected.

```
$t_str .= "viewMandatory=".$_GET['viewMandatory'] ."\n";
```

But what I need is that if $_GET is set only then it should be appended to "t_str" string.

If no value for viewMandatory is received from the form, it should print nothing. How to add this check to the above statement?

Comment: There are [a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists) of [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432282/check-if-any-variables-are-passed-in-a-get) questions, and a [Google search is quite fruitful](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-.ab&q=check+if+get+variable+exists&fp=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_GET['viewMandatory'])){
$t_str .= "viewMandatory=".$_GET['viewMandatory'] ."\n";
}
```

After 292 questions you should have encountered the empty() function.

Comment: i think you lack an enclosing `()` for the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
$t_str .= (!empty($_GET['viewMandatory'])?$_GET['viewMandatory']:null;
```

This way you have less code, what makes it easier to read (at least to me, i love short forms), but the code will be executed everytime you request the page. that is not the case with Dragon's solution.

But think about code injection. Filter $_GET['viewMandatory'] the correctway before adding it to your string! Otherwise bad code can be injected quite easy, e.g.:

```
www.yourpage.com/page.php?viewMandatory=';BAD_CODE_HERE (or " instead of ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use php isset    


if (isset($_GET['viewMandatory'])){
$t_str .= "viewMandatory=".$_GET['viewMandatory'] ."\n";
}
```