# Find how many variables are passed through url

Tags: php

I am creating a url with javascript and with location.href.  I am passing variables to the url: something like `localhost/myphp.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`.

In php, I want to take these variables but i don't know the number every time.

It may be `localhost/myphp.php?a=1&b=2` or `localhost/myphp.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`
or `localhost/myphp.php?a=1` or etc.

How can I determinate how many variables are passed and use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if any variables are passed in a GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432282/check-if-any-variables-are-passed-in-a-get)

Comment: Just use the `$_GET` array.  It'll contain *all* of the passed "variables".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those "variables", how you call them, are provided in a convenient manner to you contained in the super global `$_GET`. That array contains one entry per query parameter. So the answer to your question is:

```
count($_GET);
```

Question is however if you really need the number, since you can access each member directly: `$_GET['a']` refers to a query parameter "a" as contained in this example url: `localhost/myphp.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`. Likewise you can simply iterate over these variables:

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $val;
}
```

`$_GET` is one of a few "super global variables" provided to you when a script is requested and launched by the underlying http server. Others do exist, I suggest you take a look at the fine documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Comment: Remember that empty variables will be counted: `localhost/myphp.php?a=&b=&c=&d=`

Comment: @Berriel Yes, indeed. But empty variables are variables too, right?

Comment: just a side note for the OP, maybe he didn't notice this